# binary search tree code not working

Tags: c, binary-tree

well i was creating a binary search tree using this code..as far as i as see using this code i find it to be correct but some how its creating error  i dont know why

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct node
{  
    struct node *left;  
    int ele;  
    struct node *right;
}*NODE;

void ins(int x,NODE root )
{
    NODE temp;
    //printf("%d    %d*****%d---%d\n",root->ele,root,(root->left),(root->right));   if    i uncomment this line and then (when this function takes first root as its argument )do trace over using turbo C++ compiler its giving me root->left value not null how ever it just executes the next if statement..this should have happened
    if(x<(root->ele) && (root->left)==NULL)
    {
        temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        temp->ele=x;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        root->left=temp;
    }
    else if(x<root->ele && (root->left)!=NULL)
    {
        ins(x,root->left);
    }

    else if(x>(root->ele) && (root->right)==NULL)
    {
        temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        temp->ele=x;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        root->right=temp;
    }
    else if(x>(root->ele) && (root->right)!=NULL)
    {
        //printf("%d***%d***%d",root->ele,root->right->ele) ;
        ins(x,root->right);
    }
    //printf("%d",x);
}

void intrav(NODE root)
{
    if(root->left!=NULL)
        intrav(root->left);

    printf("%d",root->ele);

    if(root->right!=NULL)
        intrav(root->right);
}


void main()
{
    int no,i,elem[50];
    NODE root=NULL;
    printf("enter the no of elements you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        scanf("%d",&elem[i]);

    root=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    root->ele=elem[0];
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    //printf("%d---",root);
    for(i=1;i<no;i++)
        ins(elem[i],root);
    //               printf("%d",root->left);

    intrav(root);
    getch();
}
```

using for loop the ins function is executed every time that takes an array value every time and send it to the function...then if the value to be added

Comment: Telling us what error you are getting would be helpful.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it. Also, have you tried using gdb or some other debugger to step through the code? Developing your skills in a debugger will help you more than any answer you can be given here.

Comment: "its creating error".   Describe the error you are seeing (compile-time? run-time? crash? incorrect behavior?).

Comment: ..programm is crashing...using turbo C++ compiler its giving....general protection exception processor processor fault...and using gcc probably it will give segmentation fault

in 15th line see the print statement ..its not working as it should have been ... i am just not getting what;s wrong i have done

Comment: What make you think that main returns void?

Comment: @wildplasser:as far as i know in this small program its not going to matter as far as i am using turbo C++ compiler...if iam wrong please tell

Comment: "it works with my compiler" is never a reason. Compiling C with a c++ compiler is bad practice. Typedef'ing pointers is bad style and confusing to yourself and others.

Comment: ok. I would take care of it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the two `malloc`s, but I think that this is a homework, so I will not tell you exactly what it is.

HINT: Check what type `NODE` is!

Comment: NODE is **pointer** to struct node and temp is of type NODE so while allocating memory i should be using sizeof (NODE) so as to allocate the the size that NODE actually requires and then typecasting it to force it. am i right??

Comment: @user:  How much space do you think you are allocating?  You are calling malloc with sizeof(NODE).  And you yourself said NODE is a pointer, therefore it is **only** 4-bytes, and not big enough for the entire structure.  You need to malloc space for the full structure!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int ele;
    };

void intrav(struct node * ptr);
void ins(int xxx,struct node **hnd );

void ins(int xxx,struct node **hnd )
{
    while (*hnd) {
       hnd = xxx < (*hnd)->ele ? &(*hnd)->left : &(*hnd)->right;
       }

    *hnd = malloc(sizeof **hnd);
    (*hnd)->left = NULL;
    (*hnd)->right = NULL;
    (*hnd)->ele = xxx;
}

void intrav(struct node * ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return;

    intrav(ptr->left);
    printf("%d\n", ptr->ele);
    intrav(ptr->right);
}


int main()
{
    int no,i,elem[50];
    struct node *root=NULL;

    printf("enter the no of elements you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        scanf("%d", &elem[i]);

    //printf("%d---",root);
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        ins(elem[i], &root);
    //               printf("%d",root->left);

    intrav(root);
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```